# NOT receive Email Activation Membership Instruction in NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I used NopCommerce v3.5. Now I host my site online and I also have my own Email service provide by hosting.

I have configured Registration Method to Email Validation from Customer Settings in Admin area.

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8laa0YsNnkMd1NJRXhwS2pSMDg/view?usp=sharing

I have configured Email Account in Admin area and test it successful by built-in Send Test Email to sale@domain.com.

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8laa0YsNnkMNGhsTkhRUjZiV2s/view?usp=sharing

Now I got the problem which I cannot receive email to Activate Membership my new account register.

My question is why I don't receive Email (test fill out register form myself and my email address) to Activate Membership when Register New Account in Front-Store of NopCommerce?

Please help I really need to fix it on time!

Thank very much for any suggestions.

Comment: can you check your nopcommerces email queue? first register and immediatly check your email queue that email for that activemembership are generated or not.? if it generated then issue with your mail server and if not generated then there might be some misconfiguration on user registration activemembership.

Comment: You will need to set this new account as default to send mail.

Comment: Thank you Vinit Patel for your information. Now I can fix it.

Comment: Thank Nitin Varpe for your idea and now I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

May configure admin new user notification and then send to Bulk SMS provider, most of who offer email to SMS functionality:

```
    4) By default, the admin never gets an email about new customer pending. 
          You will have to enable this option. go to:

    Administration section > Configuration > Settings > Customer Settings

    Look for option "Notify about new customer registration" - ENABLE this and SAVE

    Now you will receive an email when ever a customer registers on the website
```